# Слово "павлин"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке взялось слово "павлин"? Ведь эти птицы тут никогда не водились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мало ли заимствованных слов в языке :)
Бананы тут тоже никогда не росли!

Заимствовано из немецкого языка, а восходит к французскому pavilion – "палатка, шатер"  от лат. papilio – "бабочка"). Птица получила это название потому, что ее хвост в распущенном виде похож на шатер, как он выглядел в средневековье.

Comment: Довольно интересный ряд. У Фасмера его, он возводит сразу к латинскому, причем не к бабочке, а именно к павлину. А его, если я правильно понял, к арабскому. 

И еще непонятно, откуда тогда "пава" взялась, если павлин заимствован через "павильон".

Comment: Похоже что изначально была - пава. Скорее всего "шатер" и "бабочка" появились как игра слов, но может и другие причины были такого изменения.